# CSP report uri request is pending in Chrome

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have added the Content Security Policy header to my web app. The CSP blocks the inline javascript and follows the other flags that I have set. But when I try to send the CSP report to my server the request is shown pending in the networks of the developer tools of Chrome version 33. The request reaches the server but I am not able to change the response as well.

Any help regarding this will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Three years later and I have CSP violation reports just chilling never sending